# why the code leads to infinite loop in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, infinite-loop

why code leads to infinite loop even when value within setState() is not changing.. we know state do not change if the current value and previous values are same. yet state is changing which is leading the component to re-render.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import logo from './logo.svg'
import './App.css'

function App() {
    const [state,setState] = useState(0)
    console.log(state)
    setState((prev)=>7)
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
                <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
                <p>
                    Edit <code>src/App.jsx</code> and save to reload!
                </p>
                <span className="App-link">Hello from codedamn :)</span>
            </header>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

i need answer. why its re-rendering when the state is not changing to new value

Answer (score -1):

React will generally optimize and not re-render a component if the state is set to the same value as before. However, in the case of functional components, the component body will still execute, and any side effects inside the component body will still occur.

In the original code you provided, the setState function is called directly inside the component body, which is considered a side effect. This side effect will execute every time the component is rendered, regardless of whether the state value has changed or not. As a result, an infinite loop is created as the component continues to re-render due to the setState call.

Comment: we know a component renders when useState receives new prop value. for initial render its understandable. but for further re-render, the prop value stays the same. as prop is same, state should not update. that means re render should not be there

Comment: you answered it wrong. setState outside a useEffect totally not equals to useEffect without dependency array

Comment: you can try. setState(9) inside a useEffect with no dependency array provided. and setState(9) without useEffect. check the results on your own